# Override Basic Auth of /oauth/token endpoint

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am having some troubles to override the Basic Auth of the `/oauth/token` found in the TokenEndpoint class. I basically want to add a custom validation of the credentials (`client_id` and `client_secret`).

Here is the configuration of the Authorization Server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService serviceProviderClientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices;

    @Autowired
    private OidcWebResponseExceptionTranslator oidcWebResponseExceptionTranslator;

    @Autowired
    private OidcMnoOAuth2RequestValidator oidcOAuth2RequestValidator;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(serviceProviderClientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer);
        endpoints.exceptionTranslator(oidcWebResponseExceptionTranslator);
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices);
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        endpoints.setClientDetailsService(serviceProviderClientDetailsService);
        endpoints.tokenGranter(oidcAuthorizationCodeTokenGranter());
        endpoints.requestValidator(oidcOAuth2RequestValidator);

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Bean
    public OidcAuthorizationCodeTokenGranter oidcAuthorizationCodeTokenGranter() {
        return new OidcAuthorizationCodeTokenGranter();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

For adding custom validation to client or user credentials you can augment [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) and assign proper user details service. Override its `additionalAuthenticationChecks(...)` method to add custom behavior.

```
public class AugmentedDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

@Override
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(final UserDetails userDetails, final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
    final User user = userDao.findByUsername(userDetails.getUsername())
                             .orElseThrow(() -> new BadCredentialsException("Incorrect username or password."));

    // custom authentication logic

    // Perform the actual authentication.
    super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);
```

Initialize the bean and assign appropriate user details service: If additional authentication check is on user credentials, then assign [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) and for client credentials, assign [ClientDetailsUserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.html)

```
<bean id="clientAuthenticationProvider" class="com.test.AugmentedDaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="clientDetailsUserDetailsService"/>
```

---

Addressing the question in a comment section:

The [ClientDetailsUserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/client/ClientDetailsUserDetailsService.html) implements [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) and it has a constructor that takes [ClientDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/ClientDetailsService.html) as an argument. Bean initialization would be like this:

```
<bean id="clientDetailsUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="serviceProviderClientDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

You can then reference this `clientDetailsUserDetailsService` to your custom `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Comment: Thank you Vijay for your answer,

Comment: I understand your solution, however I am using a `ClientDetailsService` rather than a `UserDetails`, so I am managing `ClientDetails` instead of `UserDetails` (like you mentioned in your example). The `AugmentedDaoAuthenticationProvider` takes only a `UserDetailsService`.

Thanks once again :)